# writing single query from multiple query

Tags: sql-server

i have a table reading with column

```
 [code]|[Test Mk]
  -----   -----
  1231  |  22.5
  1223  |  13.5
  1231  |  24.25
  1232  |  25.0
  ....    ....
```

---

when i Query like this

```
select [code], COUNT([code]) as Total 
from reading 
group by [code]
```

is shows this result

```
code    |Total
----     ----
1237    |728
1233    |698
1232    |701
1236    |651
1231    |655
1235    |626
1234    |636
1238    |685
```

again when i query like this

```
select [code], COUNT([code]) as FAIL 
from Reading 
where ROUND([Test Mk],0) < 24  
group by [code]
```

results

```
code    | FAIL
----    | ----
1237    | 617
1233    | 422
1232    | 60
1236    | 81
1231    | 271
1235    | 517
1234    | 149
1238    | 69
```

again when i query like this

```
select [code], COUNT([code]) as PASS 
from Reading 
where ROUND([Test Mk],0) >= 24  
group by [code]
```

result

```
code    | PASS
----    | ----
1237    | 111
1233    | 276
1232    | 641
1236    | 570
1231    | 384
1235    | 109
1234    | 487
1238    | 616
```

i want a  single query which generate result in this format

```
[code] | [Total] | [PASS] | [FAIL]
----     ----       ----     ----
 1231  |  125   |  100   |  25
 1232  |  200   |  150   |  50
```

how do i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Conditional Aggregation`

To get the `PASS` count, just count the rows only when `ROUND([Test Mk],0) >= 24`. This can be achieved like this.

```
Count(Case when ROUND([Test Mk],0) >= 24 then 1 END)
```

To get the `FAIL` count, just count the rows only when `ROUND([Test Mk],0) < 24`. This can be achieved like this.

```
Count(Case when ROUND([Test Mk],0) < 24 then 1 END)
```

`Case` statements generates `1` only when the row satisfies the condition else it will place `NULL`. Count aggregate skips the `NULL` values while counting

As a whole query

```
select [code], 
       COUNT([code]) as Total,
       Count(Case when ROUND([Test Mk],0) >= 24 then 1 END) as  PASS, 
       Count(Case when ROUND([Test Mk],0) < 24 then 1 END) as FAIL
from reading 
group by [code]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with SUM:

```
SELECT  [code], 
        COUNT([code]) as [Total],
        SUM(CASE WHEN ROUND([Test Mk],0) >= 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [PASS], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN ROUND([Test Mk],0) < 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [FAIL]
FROM reading 
GROUP BY [code]
```

Yet another one (weird):

```
;WITH [code] As(
    select [code], COUNT([code]) as Total 
    from reading 
    group by [code]
), [fails] AS (
    select [code], COUNT([code]) as [FAIL]
    from Reading 
    where ROUND([Test Mk],0) < 24  
    group by [code]
), [passed] AS (
    select [code], COUNT([code]) as [PASS ]
    from Reading 
    where ROUND([Test Mk],0) >= 24  
    group by [code]
)

SELECT  c.[code],
        c.[Total],
        f.[FAIL],
        p.[PASS]
FROM [code] c
LEFT JOIN [fails] f
    ON c.[code] = f.[code]
LEFT JOIN [passed] p
    ON c.[code] = p.[code]
```